# Retrieve columns from OUT REF_CURSOR using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm new at Oracle, I would like to build a solution to get columns from a return `REF_CURSOR`, and there are some limitations on creating database objects on DB,
so I want to run the stored procedure and return the `REF_CURSOR` data in C# scripting.

Comment: Can you post some code? Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting a response.

Comment: You should use ODP.NET, and then read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featRefCursor.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your back-end procedure could be something like this:

```
procedure my_proc(
    p_id in number,
    p_cursor out sys_refcursor
) is
begin
    open p_cursor for
       select  col1, col2, col3
       from my_table
       where id = p_id;
end my_proc;
```

And then in your C# script you declare the 2 parameter call, setting the second parameter as output (direction = ParameterDirection.Output) and type OracleDbType.RefCursor (remember adding name spaces 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' and 'Oracle.DataAccess.Types' at the beginning of your object/class).

Don't forget close the data reader as well as your connection,  otherwise you'll have your DBA knocking at your door with red eyes and bloody fangs.